# Create multiple pendingIntent

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

The value for myRange is always 1, 2 or 3.

It is giving a nullpointer exception error.pending must be specified.

If I do not check myRange value inside if statement, it does not give an error but it does not create pendingIntent2 and pendingIntent3.

I tried sending different Request code but it did not work.

```
  private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent(int myRange) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofencePendingIntent");
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"creating intent function" + myRange ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if ( geoFencePendingIntent1 != null && myRange == 1)
        return geoFencePendingIntent1;
    if ( geoFencePendingIntent2 != null  && myRange == 2 )
        return geoFencePendingIntent2;
    if ( geoFencePendingIntent3 != null  && myRange == 3)
        return geoFencePendingIntent3;

    if(myRange == 1)
      {
         Toast.makeText(getContext(),"creating intent 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          Intent intent1 = new Intent( getContext(), GeofenceTransitionService.class);
          intent1.putExtra("region",inString[0]);
           geoFencePendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getService(
                  getContext(), GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
            return geoFencePendingIntent1;
      }
    else if (myRange ==2)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"creating intent 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent( getContext(), GeofenceTransitionService.class);
            intent2.putExtra("region",inString[1]);
            geoFencePendingIntent2 =  PendingIntent.getService(
                    getContext(), 5, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE );
            return geoFencePendingIntent2;
        }
    else if (myRange == 3)
        {
            Intent intent3 = new Intent( getContext(), GeofenceTransitionService.class);
            return PendingIntent.getService(
                    getContext(), GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent3, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

        }




    geoRange++;
   // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "leaving my geofence", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: can you post the logcat stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems here. The first one is this:

```
       geoFencePendingIntent2 =  PendingIntent.getService(
                getContext(), 5, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE );
```

This will probably always return `null` as you you've specified `FLAG_NO_CREATE`. This will only return a non-`null` result if a matching `PendingIntent` already exists (which it probably doesn't). Use `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead.

The second problem is that you need to make sure that each of your 3 different `PendingIntent`s are unique. To do this you need to provide either a unique `requestCode` in the call to `PendingIntent.getService()` OR you need to provide a unique ACTION in the `Intent` that you pass to `PendingIntent.getService()`. Otherwise, when you call `PendingIntent.getService()`, you will just keep getting the same `PendingIntent` returned (and a new one will not be created).

There are about a million questions on Stackoverflow about this and in most of them there is a detailed explanation of how `PendingIntent` creation and matching works.